# Reading an PTM (Polynomial texture mapping) file in Python or R

Tags: python, r, type-conversion, texture-mapping, rayshader

I have several PTM (Polynomial texture mapping) files that I would like to read in either Python or R for visualisation and computing measurements. I'm not sure how to read these files and would like to work with the X, Y and Z coordinates ideally.

Examples are found here: 
http://palimpsest.stmarytx.edu/integratingdataarchive/Pal1/Acce/

- 20140220-Pal1-45-Acce-04-50m-127.ptm
- 20140220-Pal1-45-Acce-04-50m-e.ptm
- 20140220-Pal1-45-Acce-04-50m.ptm

Background information of how to build and view these files are found here, it is essentially a rayshading technique: 
http://culturalheritageimaging.org/What_We_Offer/Downloads/Process/
http://culturalheritageimaging.org/Technologies/RTI/

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried `PTMphinder` package: https://github.com/jmwozniak/PTMphinder. Reference: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6555389/

Comment: Ah ok this for visualising protein data - sorry these files are different